# making a python dictionary accessible inside a function

Tags: python, multithreading, function, dictionary

I'm building a dictionary that I then want to access inside a function. Is there any way to declare said dictionary globally instead of passing it to the function every time I invoke the func?

The reason is I want to call the function many millions of times and I'm trying to multithread using p.map() so I'm just trying to pass a single line of data to the function I'm calling..

```
def build_dict()
     file=open(f,'r')
     for line in file.readlines():    
            do_something_and_build_dict

def function(data):
     if part_of_data in dict.keys():
           do somthing

results = p.map(function,data)
```

Thanks !

Comment: Don't call it `dict` - this will shadow the built-in

Comment: once your dict is built do your multiple threads only accesses it readonly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is define your dictionary at the module level (or perhaps the class level, or whatever's appropriate for your use). As long as you don't *reassign* the dictionary name inside your function, there's nothing else you need to do.

```
my_dict = {i:i+1 for i in range(10)} # build a module-level dict

def function(data):
    # Do stuff with the global (module-level) dict
    my_dict[2] = data[-1] 
    data.append(my_dict[9])
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = function([1,2,3,4,5])
    print(result)
    print(my_dict)
```

Comment: I don't know why, but 'global my_dict' isn't working or me. When I try to access the dict inside a function I get "NameError: global name 'my_dict' is not defined". I must be doing something fundamentally wrong... I'll check the documentation.. thanks for your help